# Ubuntu refuses to boot after kernel update, claiming "PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key"

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

The version is ubuntu 18.04, and the kernel versions listed in the grub page are 4.18 and 5+ (more than one 5+ kernel).

Previously I could only boot into the 4.18 kernel version as the 5+ would stuck at "Loading initial ramdisk". Digging through some related information I concluded that this error has something to do with microcode, so BIOS was updated. (The motherboard is MSI B450I gaming plus AC)

[Previous Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgjaU.jpg)

After updating BIOS all kernels would pass the ramdisk thing described above, but still cannot boot, not even the 4.18 version kernel which previously can. This time all kernels claim "PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key" and the newer versions also claim "couldn't get UEFI db list".

[Attempting to boot kernel 4.18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdukT.jpg)

[Attempting to boot kernel 5+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qG6tr.jpg)

For the latter problem I also browsed the internet, but all the results are talking about nvidia driver etc. The point is, I use a Radeon VEGA 64 (and it did run smoothly when I still could boot). So these pages are not helpful to me.

FYI, I did tried install ROCM alongside the official Radeon graphics software, and though ROCM failed to deploy, the system was still running (both rendering and gaming on linux) till today.

I do have some work to do under linux and cannot afford losing the data stored in the drive on which linux is installed. Please help me to boot.

UPDATE: Tried recovery mode as suggested, still no luck. Ubuntu stuck claiming "VGAarb: changed vga decodes: olddecodes=io+mem, decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem". Please see the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOEn1.jpg)

UPDATE #2: Changed the boot setting from CSM to UEFI in motherboard's BIOS. Thus made sure that secure boot is off. [Please note that this option is somehow under "Windows os config" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fmQR.jpg) But still cannot boot into ubuntu, the error appears to be the same.

Comment: deactivate in uefi secure boot und try again to boot.

Comment: @nobody Also saw this solution. However according to the mother board user manual, Secure Boot is disabled by default. And no direct option to turn it off was found either.

Comment: Any chance you can boot in recovery? `dkms status`  If ubuntu is complaining cmd not found, forget my command.

Comment: @nobody No luck. Please see my update.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your hardware maybe helpful. https://gist.github.com/TomFaulkner/389e8e2e9525e11afe2e775355954cdf#work-around-ubuntu-1804-bug